# Can I use SSH tunnelling to forward a MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, ssh, command, port, forwarding

I need to login to a MySQL server, but it only accepts logins from a certain IP. On the box with this IP MySQL client is not installed, however I have a box with MySQL that can SSH into the first one. Can I use SSH tunnelling to execute the MySQL command and login, making it appear like the the first box logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
ssh -L 3306:mysql_server_ip:3306 user@bastion_box
```

Then from your local machine:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uuser -ppassword
```